# Google Reader statistics and filter

Tags: rss, google-reader

I have over 200 subscriptions in my Google Reader and I'm reading almost 300 RSS entries everyday. So my problem is to determine most powerful sources for me. So what I need to see is the statistics of my sources. Like daily activity, weekly, monthly.
Also, I want that tool give me my likes, shares based on sources. If I'm not liking or sharing a source, I assume that that's not a valuable source for me, and I want to unsubscribe from that source. So when you have 200+ source, it becomes hard to do it by yourself.

Is there any tool/service or way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Reader's trends page](http://www.google.com/reader/view/#trends-page) itself should tell you all that you need.

[image: Google Reader trends]

To head to the trends page from Google reader, the sidebar has the link to the trends page

[image]

Comment: How do you go to the trend view?

Comment: @Alex it's linked to "Google Reader's trends page". Also updated to point out how to reach the trends page

Comment: Ah, OK, I had the **Home** menu closed and couldn't see the **Trends** link. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Sathya, it helps but i need a little bit detailed stuff more than that.